# How does AtomicInteger work?

Tags: java

I didn't think threading would be this difficult *sigh*. 
Anyways, the only way I could think of executing a function after a thread has completed is to use a static counter to increment whenever a thread ran.

```
if(++threadcounter==3){doSomething(); threadcounter =0;}
```

I found this wasn't a good idea because the threadcounter at times never reaches 4.

So I used atomic integer

```
if(atomicint.incrementAndGet()==4){doSomething(); atomicint.set(0);}
```

The counter is 5 or 0 and the app freezes. I don't know what's happening. How to use a correct counter?
 Thanks

EDIT:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to tackle this is with a good old-fashioned lock:

```
boolean shouldDoSomething;
synchronized {
    ++threadCounter;
    if (threadCounter == 4) {
        threadCounter = 0;
        shouldDoSomething = true;
    }
    else {
        shouldDoSomething = false;
    }
}
if (shouldDoSomething) doSomething();
```

This will create contention on the lock, but over a very, very brief piece of code - a load, a store, and a few arithmetic instructions.

Your use of `AtomicInteger` is wrong, because there is no locking or other concurrency control linking the `incrementAndGet` and the `set`, which means there is a potential race condition (value is 3, thread A increments to 4, thread B increments to 5, thread A sets to 0).

Comment: Lol yes this is what I did to solve it! By the way I had the synchronized block inside the run method. Is that a good idea?

Comment: Other answers were great, but this is simplest. Thanks
Btw, the question still stands, is it a good idea to have the synchronized in the @Override run method :)

Comment: You should keep synchronized blocks as small as possible, so that threads do not block each other unnecessarily. That often means using a synchronized block within a method rather than a synchronized method.

Comment: Inside the run method? Are you using a single instance of your `Runnable` class for all the threads, or do they have their own instances?

Comment: each thread has the same run method. The run method has a synchronized block to increment the static variable.

Comment: Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

public void run(){
   syncrhonized(getClass())
   { 
       counter++
   } 
}
});

Comment: Okay. If you're synchronizing on the class, it should be fine. I'd be tempted to synchronize on a 'LockGuffin', an instance of Object created specifically to serve as the point of synchronization and for nothing else, just to make things more self-contained. Off the top of my head, i can't promise that no other process in the JVM will every try and synchronize that class; if it did, you might be in trouble. A LockGuffin avoids that potential risk.

Comment: Is a LockGuffin a Java thing?
What do you mean by no other process in the JVM will synchronize that class. If the class is locked, then no other process should try and use the locked code. 
Oh crap, do other threads may not use it, but what of another instance of the same application? Omfg lol

Comment: +1 `EventQueue.invokeAndWait()` is an example of a private lock object, `AWTInvocationLock`; more [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.gui/msg/1c7150ba3f137d8d?hl=en).

Comment: @Lews: What i meant about locking is that if some other thread in the JVM (not a separate OS process - that can't touch your locks) comes along and locks the class for whatever reason, that will block your threads. Phenomenally unlikely. But i favour the practice of using private lock objects to completely rule the possibility out.

Comment: Oh, and yes, LockGuffin is a Java term. I invented it a couple of weeks ago!

Comment: Thanks for your help, sorry I just saw that I had replies. I promise to learn this as best as I can!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use AtomicInteger, it's not a good match to what you want to do. Use Thread.join to wait for a thread to terminate.

Comment: I think I am with Tassos on this one.

Comment: It freezes the progressbar. Not a good soln. Well I haven't figured out how to use it

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention that - if you have a swing UI, just useSwingUtilities.runLater to run something in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

a better peice of code would be

```
if(atomicint.incrementAndGet()%5==0){doSomething();}
```

as long as it won't run over 2 billion times your fine

otherwize you can add a

```
int value;
if((value=atomicint.get())>=5)atomicint.compareAndSet(value,value%5);
```

after it but this won't be ideal as the compareandset can fail silently

or you can make you own incrementModAndGet

```
public static int incrementModAndGet(AtomicInteger atomicint, int mod){
    int old,newval;
    do{
        old = atomicint.get();
        newval = (old+1)%mod;
    }while(!atomicint.compareAndSet(old,newval));
    return newval;
}
```

Comment: Nice! The second version looks like it should do; the silent failure is benign as long as the decision to `doSomething()` is made in the basis of `value%5` rather than `value`, and as long as one of the attempts to reduce the value is successful before it hits two billion, all is well. This looks very efficient, too: i think the actions taken by the processor when executing that code are basically equivalent to a single `incrementAndGet`, or acquiring (but not releasing) a lock.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of threading are you working with? Assuming a naive approach (where you just spin), you can just call the function immediately after it breaks out of the loop.

Perhaps if you posted some more code?

Comment: What do you mean? I am just using a normal thread. 
A progress bar with timers. Then it increments the variable by 1. Except it doesn't increment right

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an applicable solution to the problem check the comments!*

You can either use [Thread.join()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) to finish threads, or if you need some counter i'd recommend a volatile primitive like

```
volatile int threadCount=0;
```

which will guarantuee ordering and immediate writing to memory. check [this page](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml) for an explanation of the [volatile](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml) keyword

hope that helps

Comment: I think I fixed it. I used a synchronize(MyClass.this)
then increment in that synchronized blocks. It appears to work, but I am not sure what synchronize does. Does it ensure that a thread must wait for another thread to finish using that block, before the thread can use the block of code? What I mean is do all threads eventually access the synchronized block

Comment: quite right. synchronizing offers thread safety guarantuees by locking whole objects, while volatile gives some less strong guaruantees only for primitive values. But volatile works without locks but by "happens before" reordering and immediate writing to memory. therefore there can not be any contention, which often happens with poorly implemented locks. But there are a lot of pitfalls with volatile (e.g. longs and doubles) you should probably read up on that if you want to use it in production: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/index.html

Comment: I assume it is ok to use then. Thanks. I will just make it a normal int and use syncrhonized to increment the counter. Thanks

Comment: -1: The use of volatile does not provide the guarantees the OP needs. Volatile provides visibility guarantees, but it does nothing to stop a race between two threads.

Comment: @Tom: so two concurrent increments to a volatile int can hide one update, so the variable gets incremented only once? i thought this was guarantueed by atomicity of int primitives?

Comment: Oh yes i see: "You can use volatile variables instead of locks only under a restricted set of circumstances. Both of the following criteria must be met for volatile variables to provide the desired thread-safety: 1. ***Writes to the variable do not depend on its current value.*** 2. The variable does not participate in invariants with other variables." from ibm dev works

Comment: Exactly. The potential race is A reads X, B reads X, A writes X+1, B writes X+1. Volatility would ensure that the reads saw the results of any previous writes, and the writes were visible to any subsequent reads, but it would not prevent the race. The thing to remember is that although ++ is a single operator, it actually involves two completely separate memory operations.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to execute some task, potentially generating a value, in another thread, and then in the initial thread make use of the generated value.

The `Callable` interface is possibly what you want.

```
final Callable<Integer> task = new Callable<Integer>() {
    @Override public Integer call() {
        // do computation
        return <some-integer>;
    }
};
Future<Integer> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(task);

// you can do other stuff here, in your thread. the task will be executing

Integer result = future.get();
```

`Future#get` will block until the thread is complete.

Comment: I have a similar use case, trying to convert AsyncTasks to ExecutorService to return a List from a Room database. Another answer suggests using submit() on ExecutorService and get() on the Dao method (see stackoverflow.com/questions/52242933/room-database-query). Would appreciate your thoughts on that approach versus your approach using a Callable and a Future.